# Ordering of conflict sets in conflict-based backjumping

Tags: backtracking, constraint-programming

If, during backtracking there is a conflict at variable `X_j`, conflict-based backjumping jumps to the most recent node `X_i` from the conflict set of `X_j`, `conf(X_j)`.

Moreover, `X_i` **absorbs** the conflict set of `X_j`, that is

```
conf(X_i) = conf(X_i) U conf(X_j) - {X_i}
```

What happens if there is an overlap between the two conflict sets? How is the absorption working in that case?

e.g.

```
conf(X_i) = {X_1, X_2, X_3}
conf(X_j) = {X_4, X_5, X_3, X_i}
```

What will be the ordering after the absorption?

Answer (score 0):

According to [prosser](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.225.3123&rep=rep1&type=pdf), the order will be as conf(X_i).union(conf(X_j)).